# react-router-dom v ^5.2.0 Routes troubleshooting

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

with all my react-apps that I've been working with,this configuration worked perfectly,but for now,routes won't render,I get my url changed but page is still the same,even 404 page isn't working

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from './LandingPage';
import AuthFlow from './AuthFlow';
import NotFound from './404';
import Nav from '../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Login from './AuthFlow/Login/Login';

function RootNavigation() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav></Nav>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact to='/' component={LandingPage}></Route>
        <Route exaect to='/login' component={Login}></Route>
        <Route to='*' component={NotFound}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default RootNavigation;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import RootNavigation from './layouts/RootNavigation';

function App() {
  return <RootNavigation></RootNavigation>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the pathnames through the prop `path` to the `Route` component.

```js
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage}></Route>
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound}></Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: AAAHH,god bless you,indeed,when I was writing this I forgot about path

Answer (score 1):

`to` prop is used for `<Link>` component to go the specific page.
Try use `path='/page'` with `exact` props on the `Route` component.